# What do these lyrics in "Angeline the Baker" mean?

Tags: lyrics, meaning, folk

In the song "Angeline the Baker," the lyrics go:

*Angeline the baker, age of 43*

*Fed her sugar candy, but she still won't marry me*

What does "fed her sugar candy" mean? Is it referring to sweet talking/flattery? Kissing? Sexual intercourse? Literal candy?

Comment: It means sweet talking